# How to implement a sequential Kalman filter for a non-linear system?

Tags: simulink, sequential, kalman-filter

I am currently working on a project in which I need to implement a Kalman filter for data fusion in Simulink. As this system is non-linear, I have thought about implementing an extended Kalman filter. However, as a matter of safety, I need to be able to "shut down" a defective sensor, and thus not take into account the erroneous values he may deliver.

The sequential Kalman filter would be a nice solution, as taking out a measure simply means to ignore the corresponding iteration. Now, the only implementations of the sequential Kalman filter I have found are for linear system. (as, for a standard Kalman, the measure z is z = Hk * x + w, and in my case, it is z = Hk(x) + w)

Could anybody tell me if there is a simple way to implement such an extended, sequential Kalman filter? The way I tried (mixing up both - substituting hk(x) to hk) did not work.

Please tell me if this question would be more adequate on the Math board.

Have a nice day,

Comment: I propose you to linearize you'r non-linear model in every point of signal. Then you can use normal Kalman. The only trick is that you can't set small  sample time, because CPU will not be able to perform all calculations.

Comment: The problem is that my system is not only non-linear (i.e. trigonometric), but also is each term of H depend of several parameters at once.
Yet I managed to get my extended sequential Kalman filter to work, by assuming every measure as independent, having R and Q being strictly diagonal (which is required for the sequential part), and keeping the formulas of the extended. It seems to work.
I don't know what part I have done wrong, as I have redone from scratch the whole thing and it magically seems to work.
Thank you for your advice.